# Pelvis Movement

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, transforms, 3d-manipulator

[image]

I want this bone to only manipulate the hip, I have checked the weight paint and it is correct. I know it's a beginner's mistake but I would like that when moving the bone the ENTIRE MODEL DOESN'T MOVE

Answer (score 0):

The whole model moves because every bone of the rig is child of the hip bone (or child of a bone that is child of it).

To get what you need you can set a master bone:

Go to edit mode, select the hip bone and make a duplicate (shift D), then select the two thigh bones, shift select the old hip bone, shift select the spine bone on top of it, shift select the new bone (this must be the last selected, so that it's active), press Ctrl P > Parent with "Keep offset".

If you have an animation, it will work only if you swap the names between the hip bone and the newely created one.